# How to create a "Secret"like table view animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, core-animation

I want to get a similar animation of a table view like secret when you click the setting button:

[image]

Of course in real-life its much more smooth..in the gif also its a bit clumsy, the cells are coming from the bottom and bouncing to the top...

This is my my table view controller class:

```
#import "StackTableViewController.h"
#import "Target.h"
#import "StackTableViewCell.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@interface StackTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultController;

@end

@implementation StackTableViewController

- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"StackTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
        [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
        Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.currentTarget = current.body;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.currentTarget = current.body;
}


- (void)back {

}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
       NSLog(@"did go back");

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

// just to ignor a warning
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.fetchedResultController.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}




- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    [[stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target];
    [stack saveContext];

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

    Target *newTarget = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:path];

    self.currentTarget = newTarget.body;

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StackTableViewCell";

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    StackTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.cellLabel.text = target.body;

    cell.cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:20];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


- (NSFetchRequest *)targetsFetchRequest {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Target"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return fetchRequest;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultController {

    if (_fetchedResultController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self targetsFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:stack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    _fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultController;

}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        default:
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to add a custom animation in the `willDisplayRowAtIndexPath` method. Past that, it's going to be a complex algorithm and a lot of work (out of scope for an SO answer) to get it to animate like that.

Comment: This is basically an adaptation of the same technique you see with the springy scrolling of bubbles in Messages. Apple showed how to do that in the Scroll Views session at WWDC 2013.

Comment: @rickster could you please attach a link to that session.

Comment: there is also some useful information about collection view animations here: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html

Comment: @rickster thanks man. what did you mean by link to the session?

Comment: I updated the table view and added a bounty :)

Comment: @rickster is referring to WWDC 2013 session 217 http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/217?q=layout%20collection%20view

Comment: @AaronBrager where am I mentioning an apple session...? and why is your link related to my question? thanks

Comment: @JohnBigs rickster mentioned the WWDC scroll views session in his comment above. The session includes code that creates a similar effect using UIKit Dynamics.

Comment: What have you tried so far as far as animating? You should clean up your question to include only relevant blocks of code instead of just dumping a whole file and asking for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Animating UITableViewCells in Swift

Maybe something like this can help?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
    animateRows()
}

func animateRows() {
    let cells = tableView.visibleCells
    
    for cell in cells {
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tableView.frame.height)
    }
    
    var delay = 0.0
    for cell in cells {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.transform = .identity
        })
        delay += 0.05
    }
}
```

### Here is what it looks like in action

[image: Animating UITableViewCells]

Answer (score 2):

You need to make changes to your model inside an 'update block' for the tableView.  At the beginning and end of this update block the model must be in synchronicity with the table or you'll get an NSInternalInconsistencyException (I may have that name slightly wrong..) and your build will crash.

So in practice you need an instance variable to store what is going on, and you change this variable inside the update block and instruct the table to insert/delete cells and/or sections in order to reflect these changes.  Please refer to my answer to this recent question, It is a whole UIViewController subclass, but look to the methods in the three tableView #pragma marks for how it  is working.  Good luck.
[Expand and Collapse All Table View Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592847/expand-and-collapse-all-table-view-cells/27595366#27595366)

Comment: It's basic ingenuity, persistence, and a knowledge of what's going on internally. Your answer is perfect, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that everything visible will be there, with no cells outside the table, you can apply an animation to the cellForRow: atIndexPath: loadTime. But you can't animate cells outside the table without Apple asserting. I would use this method, least cost, then set a handler for when the anim finishes so you can resize the table back.

Otherwise you'll have to do that row animation stuff.

Comment: what do you mean cell outside of the table? like that you need to scroll to see them?

Comment: You can't animate cells into/out of their respective data model viewForIndex stuff, it will crash. I've done it. But when the table's loaded, with all the cells, it is possible to animate them to-from random areas. I use this trick in a certain app for a certain console, unfortunately I am unable to say. Just know it is used.

I am pretty certain we both got downvoted by the same person, and that person must believe I'm wrong. I personally didn't believe it was possible until I worked on the app

Comment: I don't care about the hater who down voted. the thing is i'd love to get practical details (code) based on my code, this is why I offered 50p bounty...thanks bro

Comment: Just basic animations. I read the core animation guide, you'll want to use layers instead of view animations. Everything you need is in it.