# Expand and Collapse All Table View Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need some UI advice.

I have a view that needs to load data formatted like this:

```
    {
      "heading": "This is a header",
      "content": "This is some detailed content about the header"
    },
    {
      "heading": "This is another headline.",
      "content": " These are more details about the headline. "
    }
```

Here are the parameters: On load, it should just display the headings in a table view. Tapping a heading will expand that cell and load the the content or details about it. Here is a rough sketch:

#### On Load:

- Heading 1
- Heading 2
- Heading 3
- Heading 4

#### On Tap of Heading 2:

- Heading 1
- Heading 2

  - Content for Heading 2 get displayed here
- Heading 3
- Heading 4

There also needs to be a bar button item that will either expand or collapse all cells. Which would like this:

#### Collapse All:

- Heading 1
- Heading 2
- Heading 3
- Heading 4

#### Expand All:

- Heading 1

  - Content for Heading 1 get displayed here
- Heading 2

  - Content for Heading 2 get displayed here
- Heading 3

  - Content for Heading 3 get displayed here
- Heading 4

  - Content for Heading 4 get displayed here

I used some weird parent/child logic to get the individual cells to expand, but I think I went down a dark path because now I am trying to implement the expand/collapse all and I am stuck.

Does anyone know of any open source code that does this type of accordion table view and/or any suggestion on how to setup a view controller to do this? I have seen a few libraries expand and collapse individual cells, but being able to do all of them is getting tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I do it, perhaps a slightly simpler, although definitely similar approach :)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

//dont worry, the header is empty except for import <UIKit/UIKit.h>, this is a subclass on UIViewController

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;


@end

@implementation ViewController
{
//ivars
  BOOL sectionIsOpen[4]; //we will use this BOOL array to keep track of the open/closed state for each section.  Obviously I have the number of sections fixed at 4 here, but you could make a more dynamic array with malloc() if neccesary..
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  tv.dataSource = self;
  tv.delegate = self;

  [self.view addSubview:tv];
  self.tableView = tv;

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
-(NSInteger )numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
  return 4;
}

-(NSInteger )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return ((sectionIsOpen[section]) ? [self numberOfRowsInSection:section] : 0);
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

  //put your switch() here...

  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am section %i", (int)section ];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  static NSString *cellId = @"cellID";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];
  }


 //etc etc decorate your cell...
  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %i / %i", (int)indexPath.section, (int)indexPath.row ];


  return cell;
}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

  const CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 40.0 );

  UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:fr];
  [btn setTitle:[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
  [btn setTag:section];
  [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionOpenToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


  // add an image, colour etc if you like

  return btn;
}



#pragma mark - tableViewHelpers

//the number of rows in sectionX when it is open...
-(NSInteger )numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger )section{

  return section + 1;
}

//opening/closing a section
-(void )setSection:(NSInteger )section toOpen:(BOOL )open{

  if (open != sectionIsOpen[section]) {

//build an array of indexPath objects
    NSMutableArray *indxPths = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self numberOfRowsInSection:section]; i ++) {

      [indxPths addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section ]
       ];

    }


    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (open) {
      [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indxPths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      //nb there is a large ENUM of tableViewRowAnimation types to experiment with..

    }else{
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indxPths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
    sectionIsOpen[section] = open;
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

  }
}

-(void )sectionOpenToggle:(id )sender{
  [self setSection:[sender tag] toOpen: !sectionIsOpen[[sender tag]] ];
}

// open/close all sections.
-(void )setAllSectionsOpen:(BOOL )open{

  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]; i ++) {
    [self setSection:i toOpen:open];
  }
}


//these two for your convenience, hook up to navbar items etc..
-(IBAction)openAllSections:(id)sender{
  [self setAllSectionsOpen:YES];
}
-(IBAction)closeAllSections:(id)sender{
  [self setAllSectionsOpen:NO];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native english speaker, so if some of my explanations aren't clear enough, tell me, and I'll try to rephrase them.

Anyway, could be better ways to do it, but that was just at the top of my head,
The below code might look scary and complicated, but I personally think it is really
straight-forward,
I've just added a lot of comments, explaining each step, so the code actually not as
long/complicated/messy as it might appear at first glance.

From your example above, it seems to me that your data source is an `NSArray` which contains `NSDictionary` objects,
And that each `NSDictionary` contains one header (section), and only one content (row) for that section,
So the below example is set to handle just that- a table view, with multiple sections, and one row on each section,
Which its data source is `NSArray` which contains `NSDictionary` objects.

Since I don't know if your current data source is mutable or not, in my example I will first create an mutable copy of it, and will use it throughout the code.

Throughout the code I will assume `self.tableView` is your table view, and `self.dataArray` is the array of dictionaries you've posted above,
I also assume that you've already set the table view's `delegate` and `dataSource` to be `self`, either in code or in storyboard.

```
// Here we define the height of each header,  
// I've arbitrarily chosen 50 points. You can change it as you like.  
// The reason I've declare it like this, is that I'm using its  
// height to also create a UIView for the header, so this way  
// if you want to change the height, you need to only change it once.
#define kHeaderHeight 50

-(void)viewDidLoad {  
    ...  
    ...  
    // The method below will be called to create an mutable copies of the  
    // dictionaries in your data source, plus add them another object  
    // which will indicate in our code if the correspond header  
    // should be expanded or collapsed  
    [self createDataSource];  

    // The below line is not mandatory, but I personally like to add it  
    // So collapsed sections won't have the row's 'bounds' under them.
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];  
    ...  
    ...  
}  

-(void)createDataSource {  
    // Here we are basically going to create a temporary mutable array,
    // then we are going to iterate through self.dataArray array,  
    // Make a mutable copy of every dictionary in it, Add a BOOL value  
    // it that indicates if the row is expanded or not, add the new mutable  
    // dictionary to the temporary array, and then make self.dataArray  
    // point to an immutable copy of the new array we've created  

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < [self.dataArray count]; i++) {  
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self.dataArray[i] mutableCopy];  
        [dict setObject:@(NO) forKey:@"expanded"];
        [array addObject:dict];  
    }  

    self.dataArray = [array copy];  
}  

// Now we will set the height of each header.  
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {  
    return kHeaderHeight;  
}  

// Here we create a custom view for the header, so we can make its title clickable,  
// That will expand/collapse each section
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {  
    // Here we are creating a view for the header, and use our defined header  
    // height to set its height appropriately.  
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, kHeaderHeight)];  
    // Then create a button  
    // I've arbitrarily chosen a size of 100x20 and created a frame to be placed in the  
    // middle of the above header
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(header.frame.size.width/2 - 50, header.frame.size.height/2 - 10, 100, 20)];  

    NSString *headerTitle = [self.dataArray[section] objectForKey:@"heading"];
    [button setTitle:headerTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

    // We set the button tag to correspond to its section for future use
    button.tag = section;  

    // I've arbitrarily chose to set the button colour to gray colour  
    button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    // Then we need to actually add an action to the button  
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
    // Then we need to add the button to the header view itself  
    [header addSubview:button];  

    return header;  
}  

// Here we are just setting the number of sections to correspond to the  
// number of items we have in our data array
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.dataArray count];
}  

// Here we are finally using the BOOl value we've added to our dictionary at the  
// beginning of our code. If the "expanded" BOOL value is YES, return 1 row,  
// else, the section is collapsed, so return 0 rows
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if([[self.dataArray[section] objectForKey:@"expanded"] boolValue]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}  

// Here is just a simple method to create the cells that will use our dataArray  
// as their source for their title  
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *identifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"];

    return cell;
}  

// This method being called when clicking on the table view's headers  
// it uses the button tag we've set earlier, to determine which section we're trying  
// to collape/expand, it retrieves the current "expanded" bool value, and then store  
// the opposite value back in our dictionary (so if table was collapsed, meaning  
// its "expanded" value is NO, after this will run, it will be "YES", which  
// will be evaluated after our next line, which tells the table view to reload  
// this specific section).  
// NOTE that while our dataArray is immutable array, meaning we can't modify it,  
// it points to an mutable dictionaries, so we have no problem modifying them.
-(void)updateTableView:(UIButton *)sender {
    BOOL expanded = [[self.dataArray[sender.tag] objectForKey:@"expanded"] boolValue];
    [self.dataArray[sender.tag] setObject:@(!expanded) forKey:@"expanded"];

    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sender.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

// Connect the below methods to your collapse/expand all buttons.  
// What the below method actually does, is iterating thru all of the dictionaries  
// in dataArray, changes their value to be corresponding to what we are trying to  
// do (expand or collapse all) and then calling reloadSections:withRowAnimation:  
// on our table view.  
// You might wonder why I just don't call reloadData.  
// Although it will do the job, I like the following more, because I personally  
// feel it gives more 'smooth' update of the UI
-(void)expandAll:(UIButton *)sender {

    for(int i = 0; i < [self.dataArray count]; i++) {
        [self.dataArray[i] setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"expanded"];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.dataArray.count)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}  

-(void)collapseAll:(UIButton *)sender {

    for(int i = 0; i < [self.dataArray count]; i++) {
        [self.dataArray[i] setObject:@(NO) forKey:@"expanded"];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.dataArray.count)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Good luck mate.